# Fusion chart variable `$defaultParameterValues` found to be empty while exporting the chart as image/pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, codeigniter-2, wkhtmltopdf, fusioncharts

I am trying to display fusion 3D pie chart in a PDF export report. For this i aimed to create an image of the chart and save it in server automatically after the chart gets rendered, so that i can call that image in my pdf file. I have set the chart parameters for export like the below code 
    `<chart caption='testchart' exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='0' exportAction='save' exportFileName='testimage'exportHandler='http://mysite.com/pdf/getChartExported'>`

In my export handler file i have also set the path for "SAVE_PATH" and "HTTP_URI" constants.

My problem is
1. How will i export and save the chart as an image after the page loads
2. In export handler i get and error (i am using Codeigniter)

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: libraries/FCExporter.php

Line Number: 304
 DOMId=
 height=0
 width=0
 fileName=
 statusMessage= Export Resource not found.
 statusCode=0
```

When i checked the global variable `$defaultParameterValues` is found to be empty in FCExport handler file function `parseExportParams()`

I have being working on this for last few days. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, I am not sure, how and why as I not aware whether you have modified any part of the code, the global `$defaultParameterValues`, that I find the php file is defined as the following:

```
$defaultParameterValues = array( 
"exportfilename"       => "FusionCharts",
"exportaction"         => "download",
"exporttargetwindow"   => "_self",
"exportformat"         => "PDF"
);
```

is not being referenced inside the function `parseExportParams` and thus getting an undefined array which can not be iterated!!

One way to resolve this is to get the original `FCExporter.php` from the FusionCharts pack and then replace this with you own or do a diff of the two files to check if you have modified anything anywhere that is breaking this.

The other way is:

to check whether `$defaultParameterValues` is an array and if not - instantiate it.

```
if (!isset($defaultParameterValues)) {
$defaultParameterValues = array();
}
```

Meanwhile, there is anther alternative to extend the parameters with default values:

Modify the `parseExportParams`  to replace the existing:

```
foreach ( $defaultParameterValues as $key => $value )
{
    // if a parameter from the default parameter array is not present
    // in the $params array take the parameter and value from default
    // parameter array and add it to params array
    // This is needed to ensure proper export  
    $params [$key ] =  @$params[$key ] ? $params[$key ] : $value ;
}
```

with

```
if (isset($defaultParameterValues) && is_array($defaultParameterValues)) {
    $params = $params + $defaultParameterValues;
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I was able to sort out the php warning message but i am still getting 
   `DOMId=
    height=0
    width=0
    fileName=
    statusMessage= Export Resource not found.
    statusCode=0` message

Comment: Do you have the Resources folder (and its 2 PHP files) along with FCExporter.php? The resources are present in this folder and any one of them gets dynamically loaded by PHP. Seems the resources file is not getting included and hence this statusmussage.

Comment: Thanks its working now. My resource folder was not getting loaded.